# Flat category URLs but retaining hierarchy?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have the categories as follows:

```
- Beauty
-- Hair
-- Makeup
```

WP expects the URLs to be:

```
/beauty
/beauty/hair
/beauty/makeup
```

Is it possible to have the following links while still keeping the hierarchy on the backend?

```
/beauty
/hair
/makeup
```

Comment: I want to ask an odd question: If you want to have the hierarchy, but don't want to show 'em, then why do you need the hierarchy? Maintaining same category step, you can have different hierarchy with Custom Menus. So why do you need different hierarchy?

Comment: More of a request from the client, but they'd like the hierarchy when navigating the site, but want the urls to not change in case they move categories around (which they plan to do a lot as they experiment).  Regardless of any 301's, they don't want to confuse the user or deal with any SEO implications of these changes.

Thanks